# Comparing two files in AWK

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have two `.txt` files and I want to check if the contents of one file are present in the other or not. My `Book1.txt` contents are:

```
PATX248
PATX216
PATX203
PATX219B
PATX212
PATX248
PATX211
PATX190
PATX222
PATX241
B8025
B1003
B8063
B8032
C0999
C1035
B1011
```

My `InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt` is:

```
B8061P3 366-L4/26/2017 1
PATX-148 P3 4
 1003P4 M#1N-L1/19/2017
B1011P5 330-L2/23/2017 1
B8032P3 336-L3/10/2017 1
B1011P5 329-L2/14/2017 1
PATX-60P5 279-L2/8/2017 1
PATX-70 P3 5
B1573P6 1R-R8/10/2017 1
B8025 P4 5
B8025 P5 1
 1061P3 372-R4/26/2017
 2078 P4M#1RR-R8/25/2017
C0999 P5 4
B8078 P4M#1N-R8/25/2017 2
C-1008 P4 1
PATX-55 P4 4
B1003P5 325-R3/3/2017 1
PATX-45P4 266-L2/14/2017 1
B8032P4 384-R4/26/2017 1
C-1035 P3 1
B8032P3 340-R3/17/2017 1
```

Output:

```
B1003P5 325-R3/3/2017 1
B8032P3 336-L3/10/2017 1
B8032P4 384-R4/26/2017 1
B8032P3 340-R3/17/2017 1
C0999 P5 4
C-1035 P3 1
B1011P5 330-L2/23/2017 1
B1011P5 329-L2/14/2017 1
```

I have used all the solutions I could search on google, they all are getting executed but no result is being printed. The solutions that I tried are:

1. `grep -v -F -x -f Book1.txt InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt` (tried grep all forms of flag)
2. `awk 'NR == FNR {Book1[$0]++; next} ($0 in Book1)' Book1.txt InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt`
3. `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{print $1}' Book1.txt InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt`
4. `grep "$(cat Book1.txt)" InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt`

I want to find if the contents of `Book1` are present in `InventorySheet` or not.

Comment: Usually tools like `sdiff` or `diff` as used for this task `diff -u file1 file2 > outputfile` based on the output you can determine whats there and whats not.

Comment: There are no fields or lines in common between the 2 files so of course you're not getting any output when trying to find the common fields. [edit] your question to show the output you expected to get so we can better understand what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I have edited the question with the output. There are lines in common.

Comment: Please explain your logic: given your sample data, how to generate the output?

Comment: the code should check if the contents of Book1 is present in the inventorysheet or not. For example, C0999 is present in Book1, so it will check in the inventorysheet if there is any line containing C0999 and will print that line. I hope this will clear the doubt

Comment: Why is `B8025` missing from your output? Why is `C-1035` in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I get it now: the contents of Book1 are supposed to be the **prefix** (with, it seems, an optional hyphen) of the lines of InventorySheet. So, given `B1003` in Book1 we match the `B1003P5` line in InventorySheet. Or `C1035` matches `C-1035`.

```
grep -Ef <(sed -E 's/^/^/; s/([[:alpha:]])([[:digit:]])/\1-?\2/' Book1) InventorySheet
```

That uses sed to generate the extended regular expressions from the Book1 file, and the process substitution allows up to hand grep a "pseudo-filename".

Given your sample files, this outputs

```
B1011P5 330-L2/23/2017 1
B8032P3 336-L3/10/2017 1
B1011P5 329-L2/14/2017 1
B8025 P4 5
B8025 P5 1
C0999 P5 4
B1003P5 325-R3/3/2017 1
B8032P4 384-R4/26/2017 1
C-1035 P3 1
B8032P3 340-R3/17/2017 1
```

In awk, this would be

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {book[$1]; next}
    { 
        key=$1
        gsub(/-/, "", key)
        for (b in book) 
            if (key ~ "^"b) {print; break}
    }
' Book1 InventorySheet
```

Comment: It is giving me an output like this:-
not in InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt: B1011
not in InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt: PATX203
not in InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt: PATX226
not in InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt: PATX193
not in InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt: PATX231
not in InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt: C0999
not in InventorySheet2finaloutput.txt: PATX204

( I ran your code on my enter file, so you might see names that are not in the example)

Comment: Answer updated. Still does not match your desired output. You can explain to me why.

Comment: Your code is for sure getting executed but it is not giving any output. The same thing happened when I used grep as well. This is how my cygwin window appears:-

MSinha@ITSW2LJHT32 ~
$ grep -Ef <(sed -E 's/^/^/; s/([[:alpha:]])([[:digit:]])/\1-?\2/' Book1.txt) In

MSinha@ITSW2LJHT32 ~
$

It is not printing the output. Do you have any idea why is it happening that way?

Comment: I bet your files have windows-style CRLF line endings so the patterns have carriage returns that don't appear in the middle of the lines you're matching against. Add this into the sed command : `s/\r$//`

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell this does what you say want and the posted expected output in your question is wrong:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    key=$1
    gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"",key)
    match(key,/^[[:upper:]]+[[:digit:]]+/)
    key = substr(key,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
NR==FNR { keys[key]; next }
key in keys

$ awk -f tst.awk Book1.txt Inventory.txt
B1011P5 330-L2/23/2017 1
B8032P3 336-L3/10/2017 1
B1011P5 329-L2/14/2017 1
B8025 P4 5
B8025 P5 1
C0999 P5 4
B1003P5 325-R3/3/2017 1
B8032P4 384-R4/26/2017 1
C-1035 P3 1
B8032P3 340-R3/17/2017 1
```